# Elasticsearch query in Python does not return All of the results

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am new to python and elastic search and I have written an elasticsearch python query code which has to receive some data (keyword or category) and send a query to the ES database; then retrieve and print the matching data in my console:

```
def SingleKeywordQuery (keyword):
    response = es.search(index="main-news-test-data",body={"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"multi_match":{
            "query":      keyword,
            "fields":     [ "content", "title", "lead" ]
        }}})
    return(response)
  
def SingleCategoryQuery (category):
   response = es.search(index="main-news-test-data",body={"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"match":{"category": category}}})
   return(response)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    keyword = input('Enter Keyword: ')
    category = input('Enter Category: ')
    mapCategory = Mapper(category)
...
    elif keyword != '' and mapCategory is None:
      data = SingleKeywordQuery(keyword)
      print(data)

    elif keyword == '' and mapCategory is not None:
      mapCategory = eval(mapCategory)
      print(mapCategory)
      data = SingleCategoryQuery(mapCategory)
      print(data)

    elif keyword == '' and mapCategory is None:
      print('Please select a filter')
```

The problem is, that my code only retrieves one of the results. like, I know for a fact that there are 3 data with the category number that I want or 2 data with the keyword that I want but it only returns one. what seems to be the problem?

Edit: Data Mapping of Elasticsearch

```
PUT /main-news-test-data
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "content": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lead": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "agency": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "date_created": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "url": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "image": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "id":{
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and this is the BULK data that I uploaded using Bulk API:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "1" } }
{
  "content":"\u0641\u0647\u06cc\u0645\u0647 \u062d\u0633\u0646\u200c\u0645\u06cc\u0631\u06cc: \u0627\u06af\u0631\u0686\u0647 \u062f\u0631 \u0647\u06cc\u0627\u0647\u0648\u06cc ",
        "title":"\u06a9\u0627\u0631\u0647\u0627\u06cc \u0642\u0627\u0644\u06cc\u0628\u0627\u0641",
        "lead":"\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0647&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;\u0634\u0647\u0631\u06cc -.",
        "agency":"13",
        "date_created":1494518193,
        "url":"http://www.khabaronline.ir/(X(1)S(bud4wg3ebzbxv51mj45iwjtp))/detail/663749/society/urban",
        "image":"uploads/2017/05/11/1589793661.jpg",
        "category":"15",
        "id":"2981643"
}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "main-news-test-data", "_id" : "2" } }
{ 
....
```

Comment: can you add what that `3 objects` look like ?? i mean you said you're expecting `3 data` - i'm asking that .

Comment: and also please add what is your elasticsearch `mappings` ??

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat added

Comment: and what are you entering inputs for these 2 lines : `keyword = input('Enter Keyword: ')
    category = input('Enter Category: ')`  ?? for which your query is failing to return expected number of documents ??

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat both. for the keyword, I enter a string and for category I again enter a string which gets mapped to a number by a mapper function that I didnt include here. both of them only return 1 result and not the rest

Comment: so you will be passing something like `\u0641\u0647\u06cc\u0645\u0647` for category ?

Comment: i think it would be good if you add a language analyzer specific to your language